# Using "role model" as an adjective

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, adjectives

Can `role model` be used as an adjective? For example, in a thank you letter:

> Thanks to my role model friends

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its allowed (its clear, understandable) but there are better ways of phrasing it. 
In the context of a thank-you letter (that is addressed to your friends):

> Thanks to you, my friends and the best role models I could hope for.

This kind of exaggerated style is common is such contexts. In this is normal to use more words than needed. You could, for example make two sentences

> Thanks to you, my friends. You have been the best role models I could hope for.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, although some grammar rulebooks or style guides would insist you hyphenate the compound adjective: "my role-model friends".

Comment: If there is something incorrect with this answer perhaps those downvoting it should add a comment explaining the problem.